# Longtlbr formatting

Tags: formatting, longtable

I am trying to make a table that will span on multiples page and I am having lots of problem fixing the formatting. I included my table for reference.

[image]

1 - My project needs to be written in french so the "Continued on next page" would need either to go away or change language. Is there a way to  toggle off this text?

2 - I need specific rows to span multiple columns, those columns are darker in my referenced image. "Déterminer la performance nécessaire du dosimètre" needs to be 3 column wide. When looking online it said to use Setcell but when i tried, nothing change, i tried setting c=2,3,4...10 and i get no impact on my table. How can this be done?

3 - Putting bullet point inside the table also ads a tab at the start of the cell which i would like to remove. "Temps plus discriminant" needs to be aligned with "1 mm est réalisable".

Heres my code for the referenced image :

```
\begin{longtblr}[caption={Résultats importants du projet de doctorat.},
label={conclusions}] {colspec = {m{1cm}m{5cm}m{6cm}m{2cm}},rowhead = 1 ,
row{2} = {light-gray},
row{6} = {light-gray},
row{9} = {light-gray},
row{12} = {light-gray},
row{15} = {light-gray},
row{17} = {light-gray}
}
  %\begin{tabular}{m{8cm}m{4cm}m{2cm}}
Objectifs&Résultats&Chapitre\\
\hline[2pt]
\SetCell[c=3]{}Étudier et sélectionner les composantes du dosimètre\\

Dépendance angulaire azimuthale&moins de 2 $\%$ d'atténuation pour le capteur 5DOFthin &3\\
\hline
```

The table goes on for multiple page but all my problems can be seen with this part of code only. We tried using Longtable to start but other things didnt work (colors for example) so we ended up using longtlbr instead. If its possible to reproduce example with other ways, every help is welcome as long as its able to solve the 3 mentionned problems.

Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: `\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{Whatever you want}\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}` can be used to set the continuation text. See the [documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) page 39. The code you posted for `\SetCell` to make the row span three columns works for me as is. But of course you didn't post a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), so something may be different in your actual document.

Comment: Include the code for the bullet points in your minimal working example. Right now I don't know why they're indented to begin with, because I don't know how you're doing them.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass`, and end with `\end{document}` which has in preamble all needed your definition and loaded needed package and which reproduce showed table.

Answer (score 1):

- Your code fragment, extend to some MWE (Minimal Working Example), doesn't reproduce the shown table, so it is not clear, what you'd like to obtain.
- So the following MWE can serve only as staring point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption={Résultats importants du projet de doctorat.},
label={conclusions}
                ]{colspec = {X[l,m] X[l,m] Q[c, wd=2cm]},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
Objectifs   &   Résultats   &   Chapitre    \\
    \toprule
\SetRow{bg=gray!30}
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Étudier et sélectionner les composantes du dosimètre
            &               &               \\
Dépendance angulaire azimuthale
            &   moins de \qty{2}{\%} d'atténuation pour le capteur 5DOFthin 
                            &   3           \\
    \midrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- If you like to have code for more rows of your table, please add to your code fragment more rows and extent it to an MWE.

**Addendum:**
An example with list `itemize` in table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlist[itemize]{nosep, itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=*,
                  label=\scriptsize$\mdlgblkdiamond$}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption={Résultats importants du projet de doctorat.},
label={conclusions}
                ]{rowhead = 1,
                  colspec = {X[l, m] X[l,m] Q[c, wd=2cm]}, 
                  stretch=-1,%<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                             % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
                  measure = vbox,
                  }
Objectifs   &   Résultats   &   Chapitre    \\
    \toprule
\SetRow{bg=gray!30, abovesep=2ex}
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Étudier et sélectionner les composantes du dosimètre
            &               &               \\
Dépendance angulaire azimuthale
            &   moins de \qty{2}{\%} d'atténuation pour le capteur 5DOFthin 
                            &   3           \\
    \midrule
some text
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   some text
            \item   \qty{0.1}{\second}
                \end{itemize}
                            &   2           \\
    \midrule
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]